# Resolving conflict with RSQLite and RMySQL in the same session

Tags: r, rmysql

I don't *know* that this is an `RSQLite`/`RMySQL` conflict, but that's my best guess so far.

I use `RMySQL` to get data from a MySQL database, then I close that connection with `dbDisconnect()`. Then I use these data to in a record linking process using the `RLBigDataLinkage()` function in the [`RecordLinkage` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html). This function uses an SQLite database and the `RSQLite` package because there are two many possible matches to keep all of them in memory. As far as I can tell from the documentation, there is no way to explicitly close the SQLite connection.

Then I use these matches to pull a larger dataset from my MySQL database, again with `RMySQL`. I can connect to the database, but when I query, I get the following error:

```
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: MySQL server has gone away)
```

This happens even with trivial queries.

```
> dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM ann_id_info LIMIT 5")
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: MySQL server has gone away)
```

I can still query from the MySQL command line, though.

Is there a way I can disconnect an "unknown" `RSQLite` connection? Thanks!

Comment: I have noticed the same sort of conflict when using sqldf and RMySQL, but I haven't used RecordLinkage -- can you provide a simple example to reproduce the error? IIRC, we need to find a way to specify a path for the SQLite database instead of using a default.

Comment: @Jeffrey -- I wrote independent sample code, and it worked! And pored over my original code again and found that I had a subtlety bad query, which I fixed and it worked! So I'm happy now, but really wondering why my trivial query above fails after running the bad query? I am voting to close until I can produce a more repeatable problem.

Comment: @Jeffrey, The development version of sqldf (available on the sqldf web site) supports both MySQL and SQLite.  See if that solves your conflict.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck -- Thanks, I will take a look. I have always resolved the conflict in the past by adding an explicit `drv='SQLite'` to my `sqldf()` calls.